# How to Change Property by Trigger in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, triggers, winui

i want to Change Visibility of TextBlock when Text property is null or empty in wpf we can do this easily:

```
<Style TargetType = "TextBlock"> 
         <Setter Property = "Visibility" Value = "Visibile" /> 
         <Style.Triggers> 
            <Trigger Property = "Text" Value = ""> 
               <Setter Property = "Visibility" Value = "Collapsed" /> 
            </Trigger> 
         </Style.Triggers> 
      </Style>
```

but triggers is not available in uwp, how can i do this in uwp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=txt}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="">
        <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=txt}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
 </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```